# Can I customize popup camera permission default of browser?

Tags: aframe, ar.js

I'm using A-Frame with ARjs, when access camera from the phone, we have a popup ask permission and I want to customize the popup with my text, have a beautiful styles with CSS like SweetAlert. Is it possible. Thanks for your help!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't. Permission dialogues are trusted browser UI not customizable by content.